# Change checkMark color in ios7, Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

**Description**

I am developing an application, using `tableViews` and selecting properties by putting a `checkmark` for each of selected items. It drove me crazy for 2 hours, because the code was correct, but I didn't see `checkmark`.

**Problem**

Actually the `checkmark` was being loaded correctly but I didn't notice, because the background was white and also the `checkmark`.

**What I want to do**

I want to change the color of the `checkmark` (possibly in `Interface Builder`) without using custom `CheckMarks` with different images on it.

Is that possible? If not possible why I am having white checkMark while the other one in another tableView is gray?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible if you are using `accessoryType` on cell.

If you want to be really flexible better create custom view instead:

```
UIImageView* tick = (UIImageView*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
if(tick == nil)
{
    tick = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Archive"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tick];
    tick.tag = 1;
    tick.frame = CGRectMake(285.0f, 20.0f, tick.frame.size.width, tick.frame.size.height);
}
```

With that you can do whatever you like, use custom images, add background etc...

If you want code to look nicer it will be better if you extend UITableViewCell and create custom class with some methods and properties to control that. I just gave you code to a quick way to achieve what you want.

Comment: The reason I wanted to do this was just not to involve too much work, because I have too many tableViews, and different custom cells. I implemented once that, but I didn't want to include the same code again!

Comment: So if you just create your base table view cell view, than you can use it across whole app pretty easily. Just use your custom class instead UITableViewCell

Comment: I am actually using it now, but check the last question added on edit. Why my checkmark is white, while by default it has grey color?